# How can I stop Scrapy scraping after 10 times of page 404?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a project that scrapes pages between two numbers. My spider is below. It starts from a number to a number and scrapes between those pages.

I want to make it stop after 10 consecutive 404 pages. But it must save the CSV anyway until the stop position.

Extra: is it possible to make it write the number where it stopped into another text file?

Here is my log for examples:

```
2017-01-25 19:57:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://domain.com/entry/65848514>
{'basligi': [u'murat boz'],
 'entry': [u'<a href=https://domain.com/entry/65848514'],
 'favori': [u'0'],
 'yazari': [u'thrones']}
2017-01-25 19:57:25 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://domain.com/entry/65848520>
{'basligi': [u'fatih portakal'],
 'entry': [u'<a href=https://domain.com/entry/65848520'],
 'favori': [u'0'],
 'yazari': [u'agamustaf']}
2017-01-25 19:57:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://domain.com/entry/65848525> (referer: None)
2017-01-25 19:57:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://domain.com/entry/65848528> (referer: None)
2017-01-25 19:57:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://domain.com/entry/65848529> (referer: None)
2017-01-25 19:57:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://domain.com/entry/65848527> (referer: None)
```

And my spider:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from project.items import ProjectItem
from scrapy import Request

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://domain.com/entry/%d" % i for i in range(65848505,75848535)]


def parse(self, response):

    titles = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('//li')
    for title in titles:
        item = ProjectItem()
        item['favori'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/@data-favorite-count").extract()
        item['entry'] = ['<a href=https://domain.com%s'%a for a in title.select("//*[@class='entry-date permalink']/@href").extract()]
        item['yazari'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/@data-author").extract()
        item['basligi'] = title.select("//*[@id='topic']/h1/@data-title").extract()

        return item
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

for a more clean project you can make it as an extension:

**extensions.py**

```
from scrapy.exceptions import NotConfigured
from scrapy import signals
from urlparse import urlparse

class CloseSpiderByStatusCount(object):

    def __init__(self, crawler):
        if not crawler.settings.getint('CLOSESPIDER_BYSTATUS_ENABLED', False):
            raise NotConfigured

        self.crawler = crawler
        self.status = crawler.settings.getint('CLOSESPIDER_BYSTATUS_STATUS', 404)
        self.closing_count = crawler.settings.getint('CLOSESPIDER_BYSTATUS_COUNT', 10)
        self.count = 0

        crawler.signals.connect(self.status_count, signal=signals.response_received)

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler)

    def status_count(self, response, request, spider):
        if response.status == self.status:
            self.count += 1
        else:
            self.count = 0

        if self.count == self.closing_count:
            f = open('filename.txt', 'w')
            f.write(urlparse(request.url).path.split('/')[-1])
            self.crawler.engine.close_spider(spider, 'closespider_statuscount')
```

then don't forget to activate it on settings and use the new settings variables this extension is adding:

**settings.py**

```
# activating the extension

EXTENSIONS = {
    ...
    'myproject.extensions.CloseSpiderByStatusCount': 100,
    ...
}

CLOSESPIDER_BYSTATUS_ENABLED = True
CLOSESPIDER_BYSTATUS_STATUS = 404
CLOSESPIDER_BYSTATUS_COUNT = 10
```

Now you can configure the status and the count from settings.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have two questions, this works with 10 consecutive 404 pages or total counts of 404s? If it is like that, how do I have to run my project? with my spider or with my extension? (I mean `scrapy crawl ... ... ... ` )

Comment: first, scrapy is asynchronous, so it would be hard to really know you are getting "10 consecutive 404 statuses", but I will change the code to handle it anyway. Now for enabling this, you just need to do what I put on the answer, just copy the extension on a `extensions.py` file, and enable it on `settings.py` with the code shown there.

Comment: It doesn't handle consecutive statuses in general because downloader doesn't return responses in consecutive order. However of course it will do the trick because of kind of 'saturation' but not after 10 requests.

Comment: @mizhgun Accually It will response too much than 10 times after a while because these links will end at some point so I want to make it stop at this point. Thats the reason of my need this soluiton. So it is no problem that downloader doesnt return responses in consecutive order because after begining to scrape 404 links all responses give 404. I hope I could tell my story :)

Comment: @eLRuLL first it said global name signals is not defined. Then I installed signals and put import signals code to begining of extensions.py but it says "attributeerror module object has no attribute response_received" now

Comment: @JohnsonTureng sorry about that, please check code again, I imported the signals

Comment: @eLRuLL thanks it worked now. How about writing last number to txt after it stopped? I mean last 404 page id number?

Comment: @eLRuLL I think I have to do something after `if self.count == self.closing_count: ` with `response.url ` ? but I dont know how to do it :)

Comment: you could just print it: `print response.url`, or `print request.url`, if you want to save it into a file do something like `f = open('filename.txt', 'w'); f.write(response.url)`

Comment: @eLRuLL thanks for your kind reply. But I need only the number at the end of url. How can I get it? Thank you so much. You are very helpful

Comment: ok, check updated answer. Please remember to upvote if it helped you

Comment: @eLRuLL I updated the code but it dont stop after 10th 404 page now :( btw my reputation points are 13 so it doesnt count my upvote yet.

Comment: maybe it is failing silently when opening the file, try changing `response.url` with `request.url`

Comment: @eLRuLL same problem. also it creates filename.txt but doesnt write anything into it while getting 404s pages backside.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that, the simplest one could be to catch 404 errors with callback, count them and raise `CloseSpider` exception on certain condition. For example:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from project.items import ProjectItem
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "project"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://domain.com/entry/%d" % i for i in range(65848505,75848535)]
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404] # to catch 404 with callback
    count_404 = 0


    def parse(self, response):
        if response.status == 404:
            self.count_404 += 1
            if self.count_404 == 10:
                # stop spider on condition
                raise CloseSpider('Number of 404 errors exceeded')
            return None
        else:
            self.count_404 = 0
        titles = HtmlXPathSelector(response).select('//li')
        for title in titles:
            item = ProjectItem()
            item['favori'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/@data-favorite-count").extract()
            item['entry'] = ['<a href=https://domain.com%s'%a for a in title.select("//*[@class='entry-date permalink']/@href").extract()]
            item['yazari'] = title.select("//*[@id='entry-list']/li/@data-author").extract()
            item['basligi'] = title.select("//*[@id='topic']/h1/@data-title").extract()

            return item
```

More elegant solution is to write custom downloader middleware to handle the case.

P.S.: Left `start_urls` as it was in the question, however it is extreme overhead to generate list of 10 000 000 links and keep it in memory, you should use either generator for `start_urls` or override `start_requests`.

Comment: thanks for reply but this counts total 404 pages. I need 10 times of consecutive 404 pages. So it have to stop after  `404,404,404,404,404,404,404,404,404,404 .`

Comment: It is pretty hard to handle consecutiveness in Scrapy because of asynchronous nature of underlying Twisted framework and requests can be truly consecutive only if you use `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1` or emit requests one-by-one. In that case just reset count on `response.status == 200`. If you'd like to keep concurrency,  you need to create advanced logic for middleware or extension.

Comment: what about adding an `else` after `if response.status == 404 ` like that: `else self.count_404 = 0 `

Comment: Yes, that what I meant

Comment: I added `else` like I said but logs show me `DEBUG: Crawled (200) ` too much. What is wrong with that now?